# Understanding Yosida approximation of operators

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Definition 129 in [these notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/754/2006/notes/lecture-12.pdf) states:

The Yosida approximation to a semigroup $K_t$ with generator $G$ is given by
$$ K_t^\lambda := e^{tG^\lambda}$$
$$ G^\lambda := \lambda GR_\lambda = \lambda (\lambda R_\lambda - I)$$

where $R_\lambda$ is the resolvent operator, given by $R_\lambda = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}K_tf(x) dt$.

I don't understand any of the equalities in this.

First, since $K_t = e^{tG}$, shouldn't $K_t^\lambda = e^{\lambda tG}$? Now I see this multiplication in the second equality, but why is there now a resolvent operator? And I also don't understand the factorization $\lambda GR_\lambda = \lambda (\lambda R_\lambda - I)$.

Comment: I learned about the Yosida approximation in the context of a maximally monotone operator $A\colon\mathcal{X}\to2^{\mathcal{X}}$, and that context looks rather different from what is presented here. We still have resolvents $R_{\lambda A}=(I+A)^{-1}$ but the Yosida approximation I'm familiar with is defined by $Y_{\lambda}(A)=(I-R_{\lambda A})/\lambda$, which looks different. EDIT: It looks like the definition of resolvent is also different in this context?

Comment: @Zim I'll have to look at maximally monotone operators. Thm 130 in those notes says that the resolvent has the form $R_\lambda = (\lambda - G)^{-1}$  but I don't understand the connetion with the integral form (defined as $R_\lambda = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}K_tf(x) dt$)

Comment: (12.8) gives an explanation on heuristic level.

Comment: Yeah, the reference book I use is by Bauschke & Combettes; I'm not sure if it will be helpful for your definition though.